# How to change speed dials?

Tags: google-voice, contacts, user-interface

On the left-hand side of the Google Voice user interface, next to "Contacts", there is a `+` (plus) sign, and when you click it, it maximizes into a list of five people.

I did not choose any of the people on the list, how can I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you cannot change them. [See here.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=5d3061a041be4b22&hl=en)